# Retrieving the first and latest transaction date of a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, etherscan, ethereum-classic

Etherscan offers a time series of ethereum transaction of a contract address. Is there a way to retrieve this data? For example the duration mentioned here https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#analytics is **

Thu 23, Nov 2017 - Sun 8, Dec 2019

** [image]

Basically I want the duration in which a certain contract was active.

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x691f348ef11e9ef95d540a2da2c5f38e36072619aa44db0827e1b8a276f120f4

Comment: By clicking `ContractCreator:
0xba52c75764d6f594735dc735be7f1830cdf58ddf at txn 0x691f348ef11e9ef95d54` (click the address which appears after "txn").

Comment: What do you plan on using the data for?

Comment: Carrying out a sort of an analysis of smart contracts